# I am trying to add subscriber in Mailchimp through AngularJS, but getting error : Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angularjs

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://usXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists//members. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.

```
 var data = new Object();
          data.email_address = email;
          data.status = "subscribed";
          var params = JSON.stringify(data);
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxapi_keyxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/jsonp';
        var res = $http.post("https://usxx.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/xxxlist_idxxxxx/members", params);
                   res.success(
                        function(data, status, headers, config){
                            console.log('success', data, status);


                        }
                   );
```

Comment: "The response had HTTP status code 501." — So that's an error response. Something is wrong with your request. The specifics will depend on the API you are talking to. Read their documentation about how to connect to it from JavaScript (hint: They might not allow it).

Comment: `$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/jsonp';` — That makes no sense. POST and JSONP are incompatible and the content-type for JSONP is `application/javascript`.